# Importing to CosmosDB MongoDB API using mongorestore fails with retryable writes error

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, mongorestore

I'm trying to export and import data from an old MongoDB database server to Azure CosmosDB with MongoDB API using mongodump and mongorestore. But i'm having issues with the connection to CosmosDB. I'm using a connection string with the URI flag.

My mongorestore command including connection string is the following:

`mongorestore --uri="mongodb://$COSMOS_USERNAME:$COSMOS_PASSWORD@$COSMOS_HOST:$COSMOS_PORT/?maxIdleTimeMS=120000&retrywrites=false&appName=@$DB_NAME@&replicaSet=globaldb&ssl=true" --archive="$ARCHIVE_NAME"`

The error message from the command is:

`error restoring from archive 'testProdExport.archive': (BadValue) Retryable writes are not supported. Please disable retryable writes by specifying "retrywrites=false" in the connection string or an equivalent driver specific config.`

As you can see in the connection string i'm including the retrywrites=false URI parameter, but it looks like CosmosDB doesn't recognize the parameter.

Does anyone have experience with something similar?

//Edit: I've tried and verified that the connection string is working in a mongoose connection as well as in MongoDB Compass.

Comment: What is producing this message - mongorestore or cosmosdb? Drivers do not send "retryWrites" to the server, this is a client side-only parameter. The server receives it as a transaction number.

Comment: That is my question as well. I have no clue actually.

Comment: What is mongorestore version?

Comment: And what is ismaster output for the server you are restoring to.

Comment: mongorestore version: 100.1.1

{
  ismaster: true,
  maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
  maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
  maxWriteBatchSize: 1000,
  localTime: 1600175975194,
  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
  minWireVersion: 0,
  maxWireVersion: 6,
  readOnly: false,
  tags: { region: 'West Europe' },
  hosts: [ '<username>-westeurope.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255' ],
  setName: 'globaldb',
  setVersion: 1,
  primary: '<username>-westeurope.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255',
  me: '<username>-westeurope.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255',
  connectionId: 620417038,
  ok: 1
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a version of mongorestore that shipped with MongoDB 3.4. This may not be able to read recent dumps though.

The ismaster output you provided includes:

> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30

This [advertises session support](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/sessions/driver-sessions.rst#how-to-check-whether-a-deployment-supports-sessions) but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36 says cosmosdb does not support sessions.

CosmosDB is advertising support for a feature it does not implement, the tooling then (correctly) attempts to use it. This is a bug in cosmosdb.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the connection error, but introduced some other index issues.

Comment: @CMarker - What was the change you made based on this information?

Answer (score 19):

I found that the various mongotools (mongoimport, mongorestore, etc.) seem to ignore the `retrywrites=false` or `retryWrites=false` in the URI, but tacking on the option `--writeConcern="{w:0}"` allows the command to run successfully on instances that don't support retryable writes

Comment: This one worked for me with mongo 4.4 tools and cosmosDB with mongo v 3.6

Comment: This is what worked for me as well. 

mongoimport version: 100.3.0
cosmosDB with mongo v 3.6

Comment: Confirming that this works too with `mongorestore  v100.3.0` and cosmos DB with `mongo server v4.0`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, didn't have luck with appending on the connectionstring (not necessary if copied from Azure portal)

> retryableWrite=false

nor `--writeConcern w:0` switch
But I ended up trying all previous archives and the magic combination of [mongo tools](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.0.0.zip) 100.0.0 worked on CosmosDB with MongoServer v3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Attention: Please take care that this can lead to missing data in the collections you restored. Tested it multiple times with different versions of mongorestore. Use the version which is in the mongoserver archive with version 4.0.27. You don't need to provide writeConcern at all in this version. It will also display how many documents are restored instead of 0 in the newer versions.

This affects CosmosDb with API v4.0.