# Mongorestore from localhost to cosmosDb fails with "disable retryable writes by specifying "retrywrites=false"

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

mongo client v 4.4

```sh
mongorestore --host <host> --port 10255 -u <user> -p <password> --db <db_name> --collection structures structures.bson --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates

2020-10-03T23:13:44.440+0300    Failed: <db_name>.structures: error restoring from structures.bson: (BadValue) Retryable writes are not supported. Please disable retryable writes by specifying "retrywrites=false" in the connection string or an equivalent driver specific config.
```

I tried the other way

```sh
mongorestore "mongodb://<host>:<password>@<name>:10255/?ssl=true&retrywrites=false&appName=@name@" dump/
```

with the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing BSON to CosmosDB MongoDB API using mongorestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900885/importing-bson-to-cosmosdb-mongodb-api-using-mongorestore)

Answer (score 27):

I found that [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336889/14574199) `--writeConcern="{w:0}"` can solve the "rewrite=false" error. I have tried it and here's my command.

```
mongorestore.exe --uri "<cosmosdb_connect_string>" --db Database1 --collection collection1 --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates edx-dump/Database1/collection1.bson --writeConcern {w:0}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are getting the same error as I am, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This! If you run into this error specifically when attempting the mongorestore command on a Azure CosmosDB (Mongo API) instance, adding this command resolves the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and this resolved it. You can also see in the CosmosDB docs that this comment is being shown in an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/tutorial-mongotools-cosmos-db